# How to connect MySQL local database to Azure Data Studio?

Tags: mysql, azure-data-studio

I searched the documentation but I could not find out, how can I connect MySQL local database to Azure Data Studio?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available in preview (as of writing). You need to install the MySQL extension. Find the documentation and steps here [Use Azure Data Studio to connect and query MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-mysql?view=sql-server-ver16)

The gist of it is you need to:

1. install the [MySQL extension for Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-data-studio/extensions/mysql-extension#install-the-mysql-extension)
2. Select MSQL for connection type in the connection dialog
3. Enter connection settings

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to my local MySQL instance after just setting the server name to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and in the `Advanced...` settings set port to `3306`.

I originally tried to set my server name to `localhost:3306` and `127.0.0.1` with no luck.

Additionally here is what my connection looks like in `settings.json` in Azure Data Studio:

```json
    "datasource.connections": [
    
        {
            "options": {
                "connectionName": "",
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "dbname": "",
                "user": "root",
                "password": "",
                "port": "3306",
                "connectTimeout": "10",
                "ssl": "require",
                "groupId": "C777F06B-202E-4480-B475-FA416154D458",
                "databaseDisplayName": ""
            },
            "groupId": "C777F06B-202E-4480-B475-FA416154D458",
            "providerName": "MySQL",
            "savePassword": true,
            "id": "a3b754b2-248a-4550-ba65-e099e8246d07"
        }
    ]
```

[image: 3306]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As I am writing, there is no native support for MySQL database connection. You can vote for the feature on [Database Support MySQL Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/4904). However, because Azure Data Studio supports python, you can connect to MySQL database using python libraries.

Comment: I think its because python uses ODBC libraries, so any language that uses that can connect to MySQL.